# Why is Java Swing not working in Eclipse PDE - freezes during setVisible(true)?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, thread-safety, eclipse-pde

Let's assume that I have the following program:

```
public class TestGUI {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Syso 1");

    GUITest gtest = new GUITest ();
    gtest.openWindow(); //basically the main method, contains setModal(true) and setVisible(true)

    System.out.println("Syso 2");
   }
}
```

This works perfectly fine. It prints "Syso 1" then opens the JDialog and after closing / confirming it, it prints "Syso 2" and this is exactly what I want.

I intend to run this exact code in my main program, which is going to be an Eclipse plugin and therefore opens another Eclipse when I'm debugging it.

However, if I run this as a plugin, the code goes until `setVisible(true)` and then nothing happens afterwards. I don't see a `JDialog` or anything like that.

I've read something about using something like:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
            new Runnable() { 
                @Override public void run() {
                    gtest.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        );
```

This "unfreezes" my Eclipse and the program continues running afterwards, however, an `JDialog` is not opened. I want to decide what do to next based on the user input and then proceed normally in the code after the users confirmation.

**Edit:**
For some reason, it just started working on it's own. Regardless, here is what I was doing:

```
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);
    MessageDialog.openInformation(
            window.getShell(),
            "Test",
            "Hello, Eclipse world");

    System.out.println("Syso 1");
    GUITest gtest = new GUITest ();
    gtest.openWindow();
    System.out.println("Syso 2");
  }
```

**Edit 2:**

Well, maybe it's not working as intended. It works on some occasions but not on others. Someone on SO mentioned things that things like that are related to thread safety. Any ideas?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What do you mean by 'run as a plugin'? Eclipse plugins don't have a `main` method and generally are written using SWT rather than Swing.

Comment: I'm running it as an Eclipse Application using an execute method. By creating an example, it somehow started working on its own. Weird. Thanks regardless, I will edit the post.

Comment: You can't just mix Swing code in with SWT. You need to use the `SWT_AWT` class to run Swing code.

Comment: @greg-449 Could you provide an example?

Comment: There are plenty of examples around such as https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks, is the SWT_AWT code added into the swing class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116469/discussion-between-oldmcdonald-and-greg-449).

Comment: No it is part of the SWT code. You will have to write some SWT code to contain the Swing code.